# Dividing by $(x+7)$ in an equation

Tags: calculus

There is an equation:

$${9}:{(x^2+7x)} = (x+3):(x^2+6x-7)$$

I did this:

$9(x^2+6x-7) = (x+3)(x^2+7x)$

$9(x-1)(x+7) = (x+3)(x+7)x$

in the last stage, can I divide by $(x+7)$ ? It may be $0$. If no, how can I solve this equation?

Comment: It is assumed that $x\ne -7$ because otherwise $\frac{9}{x^2+7x}=\frac{x+3}{x^2+6x-7}$ doesn't make any sense. In particular $x\ne 0,-7,1$

Comment: I think $x=-7$ is potentially a valid solution. If this were a problem involving projective co-ordinates, for example, it would be possible to make sense of the ratios being equal in that case. Sometimes this notation is used to avoid explicit division by zero. When constructing fractions in contexts where there are zero divisors, for example, equivalence is established by multiplying rather than dividing - and that can be done here too, It does depend on the context, though - but if the context is right the solution makes sense.

Comment: Whatever appears on both sides and gets multiplies, you can divide and it will cancel each other out. So your x+7 is gone, meaning the solution cannot be x=-7, which is not allowed in the original equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can divide it because at $x=-7$, LHS & RHS are undefined i.e.   $x+7\ne 0$

Notice the following steps
$$9(x-1)(x+7)=(x+3)(x+7)x$$ $$9(x-1)(x+7)-(x+3)(x+7)x=0$$
$$(x+7)[9x-9-x^2-3x]=0$$
$$(x+7)[x^2-6x+9]=0$$
$$(x+7)(x-3)^2=0\implies x=-7, \ 3, \ 3$$
But, $x\ne -7$ because  LHS & RHS are undefined

Hence, the acceptable value is $\color{red}{x=3}$

Answer (score 1):

put everything in one side i.e $(x+7)(9(x-1)-x(x+3))=0$

Comment: hey. I tried in your way , and I got 2 solution: $x = (-7)$ , $x = 3)$ . but according to @user170039 , x can't be (-7) . how does it make sense that I got wrong solution?

Comment: yes. so discard -7  :)

Answer (score 1):

> in the last stage, can I divide by (x+7) ? It may be 0

Your goal is to find a solution. If finding a solution involves dividing by 0, the result is not a solution. (Not that there actually is any result from an undefined operation)

So whatever you do, keep in mind that if you end up with a solution that relies on $x+7=0$, then this solution doesn't actually exist.

It's actually similar to what you do right now. Your goal is to find the solutions or set of solutions. You operate on that equation to determine the set of solutions. You start at "*I have no freak'in idea what x is!*" and narrow it down to finally end up with something like $x=42$ (or whatever solutions you'd actually get)

Being able to tell that something is certainly **not** a solution is helpful in the same sense. You now know that $x = -7$ is not part of the solution. Admittedly, it's only one number, but hey, better than nothing!
Don't shy away from doing something that can include division by 0. Be aware of that problem and isolate it by treating those cases you'd actually divide by 0 in the special way described above: no solutions can come from these cases.